# Sum Aggregation Across Several Foreign Key Relationships in Django 3.0 with Postgres

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have some Django models that are linked via Foreign Key relationships.

An `Estimate` can have one or more `Job`s, a `Job` can have one or more `Work`s, a `Work` can have one or more `Part`.
`Part` has a `FloatField` `customer_cost`

`Part` looks like this:

```py
class Part(models.Model):
    work = models.ForeignKey(Work, related_name="parts", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customer_cost = models.FloatField(blank=True, default=0)
```

`Work` looks like this:

```py
class Work(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, related_name="work_items", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In a view for the `Work` model, I'm trying to annotate the response so that with each `Work` item, the summed `customer_cost` of all `Part` items that are linked to the same `Estimate` via Foreign Key relationships is returned.

The following I believe is summing the same items multiple times (the returned result for `jobs_total_parts_cost`  is much higher than I expected

```py
qs = qs.annotate(jobs_total_parts_cost=Sum('job__estimate__jobs__work_items__parts__customer_cost'))
```

If I specify `distinct=True` on the `Sum`, it works, but not in the case where two `Part`s have the same `customer_cost` - e.g. if two parts have `customer_cost` 10 and one part has `customer_cost` 5, the result is 15 instead of 25.

In other words, how can I specify that the value should only be summed once from each distinct part, rather than specifying that the value of `customer_cost` itself must be distinct

Any help would be greatly appreciated - let me know if I can provide any more detail

Comment: If these are all `ForeignKey`s (and not m2m's), then the `Sum(..)` *without* `distinct=True` is correct.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I thought it should work too, but to give you an example, right now there is one Estimate in the database. That Estimate has 3 Jobs associated with it. Each has 1 Work. 2 of those Works have 1 Part and 1 has 2 Parts. So a total of 4 parts, all associated with the same Estimate. The 4 Parts ```customer_cost``` fields are 50, 2, 5 and 15. 
Each item in the response from this view contains ```jobs_total_parts_cost: 288``` whereas I'm expecting ```jobs_total_parts_cost: 72```

Comment: If I add ```distinct=True```, ```jobs_total_parts_cost``` comes back as ```72``` for each item. However, if I then change the ```customer_cost``` fields on the parts to be 50, 2, 15 and 15, the result is ```67``` instead of ```82```